# update positive to negative value in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have payment table fields

[image]

update reason and amount & total field are change negative

```
UPDATE payment 
SET reason = 'refund' 
WHERE uid =5 AND date = '2012-05-01' AND accid =2
```

update single query is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you also want to set amount column to positive value along with the above statement.

You can use something like this

```
UPDATE payment 
SET reason = 'refund', amount = amount * -1, total = total * -1
WHERE uid =5 AND date = '2012-05-01' AND accid =2
```

Comment: if we did amount=amount * -1 then positive values will become to negative

Answer (score 7):

Use `ABS(amount)` if you wish to always get the positive integer.

```
SELECT ABS(5);
```

will output 5

```
SELECT ABS(-5);
```

will also output 5

Comment: I like this idea better...what is a value was already negative for some reason? Then the accepted answer would switch it back to positive, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked for the solution, the offered suggestion corrupted my result:

```
SELECT @TotalAmount:=( SELECT FORMAT(SUM(Amount),   4)  FROM MPPayment WHERE PaymentBatchID = 6 and CompanyID=3);
```

Proper result:

[image]

After formatting:

```
SELECT @TotalAmount:=( SELECT FORMAT(SUM(Amount),   4)  FROM MPPayment WHERE PaymentBatchID = 6 and CompanyID=3);
SELECT @TotalAmount * -1;
```

[image]
Probably doesn't work well with formatting.

Another solution is to subtract your digit from zero:

```
SELECT @TotalAmount:=( SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM MPPayment WHERE PaymentBatchID = 6 and CompanyID=3);
 select FORMAT((0 - @TotalAmount), 4 );
```

To avoid the corruption of the the result I described above, I make formatting at the end of the operation. The result is fine then:

[image]

Works also with multiplication by -1:

```
 SELECT @TotalAmount:=( SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM MPPayment WHERE PaymentBatchID = 6 and CompanyID=3);
 select FORMAT(( @TotalAmount *-1), 4 );
```